# Travis CI fails iOS Build

Tags: ios, swift, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am trying to build an iOS(swift) project with Pods, with Travis CI but I am getting the the following error.

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (1.2.1.beta.1) is higher than the version of the current executable (1.2.0). Incompatibility issues may arise.
Pre-downloading: `SwiftValidator` from `https://github.com/jpotts18/SwiftValidator.git`, commit `2a6c23ad9efd76127f6109445515cb9780e5ad92`
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
- `Marshal (= 1.2.4)` required by `Podfile`
- `Marshal (= 1.2.4)` required by `Podfile.lock`
None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Marshal (= 1.2.4)`.
You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
The command "eval pod install " failed 3 times.
The command "pod install" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

Here is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: swift
osx_image: xcode8.3

branches:
  only:
    - develop
    - master
env:
  - LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
before_install:
  - rvm install ruby-2.2.2
  - gem install cocoapods
  - gem install xcpretty -N
  - brew update
  - brew install swiftlint || true
script:
  - set -o pipefail
  - xcodebuild -workspace Invision.xcworkspace -scheme Invision -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO | xcpretty -c
  - swiftlint
```

Reading through the log I can see that there is something wrong with the Pods. So here is my `Podfile`

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Invision' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Invision

  pod 'ZLSwipeableViewSwift' 
  pod 'Moya'
  pod 'Marshal', '1.2.4'
  pod 'SwiftValidator', :git => 'https://github.com/jpotts18/SwiftValidator.git', :branch => 'master' 
  pod 'Log' 

  target 'InvisionTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'InvisionUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I have also read about how to solve the problem and some of the suggestions were:

`pod update Marashl` - didn't work

Any ideas of how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the code you pushed using CocoaPods 1.2.1.beta.1 but Travis-CI supports 1.2.0. `gem install cocoapods` installs the stable version of CocoaPods try installing beta version

Answer (score 0):

<s>`xcode8.3` isn't supported yet hence you might be routed to the default image which is `xcode7.3`. See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment/#OS-X-Version.</s>

Can you try with `osx_image: xcode8.2`?

**Update 2017-05-15**: `xcode8.3` is now supported: https://blog.travis-ci.com/2017-04-19-xcode-832-is-here.